# Unable to install msi file. Getting error "Windows cannot access the specified .....to access the item"

Tags: mongodb, installation, permissions, windows-8.1, access-denied

I'm trying to install mongoDb on windows 8.1 (64 bit). Everytime I click on msi file, getting error "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item". Already checked the permissions in security tab, still the issue persists. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please Try to install the msi file with system context(psexec.exe) if it works.